# Protect www directory of GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, security, apache

I use the www directory of my GeoServer to serve different maps, mostly with Leaflet.
Now I want to restrict the access with login credentials. I allready tried to get a htpasswd protection working, but this does not work in my GeoServer directories. I have GeoServer installed on Tomcat9 and Apache2 is in front of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any (easy) way to do that, the www directory was never intended for production code. You really need to use Apache to host your static pages and then redirect GeoServer requests through to tomcat and handle all you login at the Apache level.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot. I managed to deposit my maps in the html directory of my apache installation and just use the layers geoserver is serving by calling them with their absolute paths.